# How to reduce points in a list around a specific point?

Tags: python

I have no idea how to explain this concept, as if I did I probably would have found the answer on Google already.

What I'm trying to do is take a list of y points and reduce all values above and below a specific chosen point. Could be in the middle of the graph, could be at the beginning, etc.

This is easier with a picture. Here's a visualization of what I want to do.

[image]

You can see the point I chose to "reduce" the points around it.

I wrote this overly complicated function to do exactly that:

```
import numpy as np
x = [0.0, 4.8, 9.0, 11.3, 13.6, 17.1, 23.1, 29.5, 35.1, 39.8, 42.2] 
y = [1.35, 1.36, 1.39, 1.43, 1.46, 1.48, 1.49, 1.53, 1.59, 1.68, 1.8] 

squash_around = 1.43
squash_min = min([i-squash_around for i in y])
squash_max = max([i-squash_around for i in y])
y = [np.interp(i-squash_around, [squash_min, 0, squash_max], [.9, 1.0, 1.1])*i for i in y]
```

[image]

However, it fails to work correctly with some data, for example I set `squash_around` to .2, so it should modify all points except the top left, but it doesn't:

[image]

If anyone can point me to the probable duplicate question for this, that'd be great.

Comment: The graphs are nice, but it would be helpful if you could post actual numeric output from your code, matched with the result you expect in each case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like what you're trying to "reduce" is the difference in y-value between the point of interest (i.e. the circled one), and each other point's y-value.

If we let `(x, y)` be the point that you want to "reduce" around, then we can "reduce" another point `(x1, y1)` relative to `(x, y)` by a factor of `a` with the following transformation

```
(x1, y1) => (x1, y + (y1 - y) * a)
```

If `0 < a < 1` then `(x, y)` stays exactly where it is, points below `y` move up towards it, and points above `y` move down towards it. Putting this into numpy code

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([0.0, 4.8, 9.0, 11.3, 13.6, 17.1, 23.1, 29.5, 35.1, 39.8, 42.2])
y = np.array([1.35, 1.36, 1.39, 1.43, 1.46, 1.48, 1.49, 1.53, 1.59, 1.68, 1.8])

i = 5   # the index of the point to "reduce" around
a = 0.5 # reduction factor

reduced = y[i] + (y - y[i]) * a 

# plt.plot(x, y)
# plt.plot(x, reduced)
```

[image]

Is that the kind of reduction that you are looking for?

Comment: Excellent! Yes, exactly. Knew there was an easy way to do it. Thanks